# Changes in SSLEngine usage when going up to TLSv1.3

Tags: java, nio, java-11, sslengine, tls1.3

Java 11 was released with `TLSv1.3` support, used by default.

It works OK in context of HTTPS and SSL sockets, but it seems that when using `SSLEngine` there are additional hurdles due to changes in `TLSv1.3` behavior.

So there is a robust implementation of communication via `NIO` using `SSLEngine` that no longer works when `TLSv1.3` is enabled. There are no obvious errors, in form of exceptions or SSL errors, two nodes will just send wrap/unwrap messages back and forth and eventually timeout.

I am interested in an exact list of behavior changes between SSLEngine using TLSv1.2 and SSLEngine using TLSv1.3, and if possible a migration checklist between these. Unfortunately, SSLEngine javadocs of Java 11 does not have this information - no new methods in Java 11 and no reference to TLSv1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we needed to read the remaining data from buffer after handshake is finished, unwrap it and update handshake status. Looks like an edge case which we did not handle previously.

Relevant commit: [IGNITE-11298 Fixes to support TLSv1.3 in Communication](https://github.com/apache/ignite/commit/8e69ae7648f50aeab7884ae58624be0a632cdd31#diff-a44ffd4481df44aeb27dd2b62f3a2fa5)

Comment: Your fix only covers the case where the `NewSessionTicket` message immediately follows the incoming `Finished` message. It can come in at any time after that. See [RFC 8446 #4.6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-4.6). Your engine-handling code should handle this message seamlessly without requiring special cases.

Answer (score 6):

It's true that there is no explicit reference to the impact of TLS 1.3 on `SSLEngine` in its Javadoc in JDK 11, and there were no changes in its methods.

However [the fifth item (closure) in the list of phases of `SSLEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) was updated in the general description at the start of its Javadoc in JDK 11:

> Closure - When the connection is no longer needed, the client and the
>   server applications should each close both sides of their respective
>   connections. For **`SSLEngine`** objects, an application should call
>   **`closeOutbound()`** and send any remaining messages to the peer. Likewise,
>   an application should receive any remaining messages from the peer
>   before calling **`closeInbound()`**. The underlying transport mechanism can
>   then be closed after both sides of the **`SSLEngine`** have been closed. If
>   the connection is not closed in an orderly manner (for example
>   **`closeInbound()`** is called before the peer's write closure notification
>   has been received), exceptions will be raised to indicate that an
>   error has occurred. Once an engine is closed, it is not reusable: a
>   new **`SSLEngine`** must be created.

The change is also discussed in [Oracle's Release Notes for JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html):

> **TLS 1.3 Half-Close Policy**
>   A new system property,
>   **`jdk.tls.acknowledgeCloseNotify`**, has been added. The default value of
>   the system property is false. If the system property is set to true, a
>   corresponding **`close_notify alert`** will be sent when receiving a
>   **`close_notify`** alert, and the connection will be duplex closed.
>
> TLS 1.2 and prior versions use a duplex-close policy, while TLS 1.3
>   uses a half-close policy. The inbound and the outbound close_notify
>   alerts for TLS 1.3 are independent. When upgrading to TLS 1.3,
>   unexpected behavior can occur if your application shuts down the
>   (D)TLS connection by using only one of the **`SSLEngine.closeInbound()`** or
>   **`SSLEngine.closeOutbound()`** APIs, but not both in each side of the
>   connection. If your application exhibits unexpected hangs or timeouts
>   when the underlying (D)TLS transportation is not duplex closed, you
>   may need to set this property to true.
>
> Note that when a TLS/DTLS connection is no longer needed, the client
>   and server applications should each close both sides of their
>   respective connection.

So setting `jdk.tls.acknowledgeCloseNotify` to **true** might resolve your specific concern about timeouts when using `SSlEngine` with TLS 1.3:

> ***If your application exhibits unexpected hangs or timeouts*** when the underlying (D)TLS transportation is not duplex closed, you may
>   need to set this property to true.

The Release Notes document also links to the closed JDK bug [JDK-8208526 : TLS 1.3 half-close and synchronization issues](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8208526) which discusses the change in even greater detail.

The related (and closed) bug [JDK-8207009 : TLS 1.3 half-close and synchronization issues](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8207009) may also be of interest.

Other References:

- See "*Appendix D. Backward Compatibility*" of [RFC 8446](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8446/?include_text=1): "*The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.3*" (pp. 138-141).
- There's a brief discussion of compatibility between TLS 1.3 and earlier releases in this Oracle video "[*Monday Technical Sessions: Moscone West 2004*](https://youtu.be/nedOlwfp7ZM)" between 2:53:37 and 2:56:35.

Comment: Thank you for this analysis, unfortunately, it seems that app is stuck on handshake phase and `jdk.tls.acknowledgeCloseNotify` does not do anything.

Comment: @alamar OK. If you are stuck on the initial handshake then I suppose it makes sense that `acknowledgeCloseNotify` does not help. Are you using the latest version of Java 11? (i.e. 11.0.2)

Comment: Yes. I imagine there might be a subtle bug that only becomes a concern with TLSv1.3 but otherwise it would work robustly.

Comment: Note that it does not hang in OpenSSL code but just will pass messages back and forth until timeout is reached.